# Relationship between Amazon EC2 and Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

Dears,

I am new to AWS cloud platform and trying to explore. I learned about AWS EC2 and AWS Redshift. Is there any kind of relationship between these? Is it possible to use Redshift data warehouse without creating an EC2 instance on my AWS account?

Answer (score 2):

There is no *relationship* between Amazon EC2 and Amazon Redshift, aside from the fact that they can both **reside in the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)**, making it possible for them to communicate with each other privately without going across the Internet.

Accessing Redshift from an EC2 instance in the same region will also have **extremely fast connectivity**.

Aside from networking, there is no other benefit that EC2 instances have for accessing an Amazon Redshift database cluster.

Comment: Thanks, John, for the clarification !!